# Finding the Limit using L'Hospital's rule $\lim_{x\to 0} \left( {1-x\over\sqrt{1-\cos x}}-{1+x\over\arctan x} \right)$

Tags: calculus, limits

Need help with this:

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \left( {1-x\over\sqrt{1-\cos x}}-{1+x\over\arctan x} \right)$$

First I combine the fractions:

$$\lim_{x\to 0} {\arctan x(1-x)-\sqrt{1-\cos x}(1+x)\over\arctan x\sqrt{1-\cos x}}$$

This allows me to apply L'Hospitals rule, but this gives me a rather bulky equation that still is indeterminate in form:

$$\lim_{x\to 0} {{{(1-x)\over(1+x^2)}-\arctan x-{\sin x(1+x)\over2\sqrt{1-\cos x}}+\sqrt{1-\cos x}\over {\sin x(\arctan x)\over2\sqrt{1-\cos x}}+{\sqrt{1-cos x}\over1+x^2}}}$$

Is there any way to reduce this? Am I on the right track?

Comment: Did you attempt to apply L'Hopital a second time?

Comment: Is using  L'Hopital a requirement ?

Comment: I've applied L'Hospital's again and I still get an indeterminate form. And yes, L'Hospital's is a requirement for solving.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $(1-\cos(x))(1+\cos(x))=\sin^2(x)$.

Multiply the first fraction by $\sqrt{1+\cos(x)}$ before bringing it to the same denominator.

Answer (score 2):

Be careful that  you may  need to discuss $x\to 0^-$ and $x\to 0^+$

$\sqrt{1-\cos x}=\sqrt{2}\sin(\frac{x}{2})$  for $x>0$

so

$\lim_{x\to 0^+} {1-x\over\sqrt{1-\cos x}}-{1+x\over\arctan x}=\lim_{x\to 0^+}{1-x\over\sqrt{2}\sin(\frac{x}{2})}-{1+x\over\arctan x}=\lim_{x\to 0^+}{1\over\sqrt{2}\sin(\frac{x}{2})}-{1\over\arctan x}+{x\over\sqrt{2}\sin(\frac{x}{2})}-{x\over\arctan x}$

Then you can use L'Hospital's rule to evaluate the first two terms since the last two have finite limit.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that $\arctan x \sim x$ and $1-\cos x \sim \frac{x^2}{2}$ as $x\to 0$, then it will be greatly helpful for you. So

$$\lim_{x\to 0} {\arctan x(1-x)-\sqrt{1-\cos x}(1+x)\over\arctan x\sqrt{1-\cos x}}
=\lim_{x\to 0} {\arctan x(1-x)-\sqrt{1-\cos x}(1+x)\over x\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{2}}}  $$